# How to share variable with Nuxt.js from layout to pages?

Tags: variables, layout, nuxt.js

I actually work on a project that consists of display data from Jsons on a Nuxt.js website using Vuetify. I have created a selector in my layout to choose which Json the user wants to display. I need to access this variable from all the different pages of my project.

Here is what my `default.vue` looks like :

```
<template>
  <v-overflow-btn
    :items="json_list"
    label="Select an Json to display"
    v-model="selected_json"
    editable
    mandatory
    item-value="text"
  ></v-overflow-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selected_json: undefined,
      json_list: [
        {text: "first.json"},
        {text: "second.json"},
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The variable I would like to access  from all my different pages is `selected_json`.

I see many things on the internet such as Vuex or a solution that consist to pass the variable with the URL. But I'm kind of newby in web programming (started Vue/Nuxt one week ago) and I don't really understand how to apply this in my project. So if there is a more easy way to do it or a good explaination, I'm interested!

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Vuex we can easily achieve what you want.

First of all create a file `index.js` in folder `store` (if you don't have a `store` folder then create it in the same directory where your `pages, plugins, layouts etc` folders are). Then paste this piece of code in `index.js`

```js
//store/index.js
export const state = () => ({
  selected_json: null
})
```

By doing this we set Vuex up. More precisely just `state` part of Vuex where if you don't know we store data accessible across your project.
Now we have to assign data from your `default.vue` to Vuex. We can achieve this by creating a `mutation` function through which we change `state` in Vuex. Add this to your `index.js`

```js
//store/index.js
export const mutations = {
  setSelectedJson(state, selectedJson) {
    state.selected_json = selectedJson
  }
}
```

Here function `setSelectedJson` takes two params, `state` which is automatically passed in by Nuxt.js and it includes all our Vuex state data. The second parameter `selected_json` we pass in ourselves.

Now in your `default.vue` we need to add a `watcher` for `selected_json` so we can update our Vuex when `selected_json` gets updated.

```js
//layouts/default.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    selected_json(newValue) {
      this.$store.commit("setSelectedJson", newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

We are almost done.
The last thing we need to do is to make a `getter` which is used to retrieve values from Vuex. A getter like this will do its job.

```js
//store/index.js
export const getters = {
  getSelectedJson(state) {
    return state.selected_json
  }
}
```

That's it.
Now you can access `selected_json` on any page you want by simply getting it from Vuex with this line of code.

```js
this.$store.getters["getSelectedJson"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer!

Unfortunately, I still have an issue with Vuex. The getter works correctly but the setter didn't work at all. I tried a different mix between `newVal` and `newValue` but nothing happens.

In the watch event how Nuxt know to pass the new value as the parameter of `selected_json(newValue)`?

Comment: In the setSelectedJson mutation function I made a mistake and mistyped the name of one variable. Both variables should have the same name and it all should work. I even tested it before posting the answer. Do you get any errors in the console? Also the watch event is directly from Vue.js. You can learn more about watchers on official vue.js docs or here: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-watchers/

Comment: Ok thanks for the correction :)
Here is the error I get in the console :
`Property or method "selected_json" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: My bad, I easily fix it. Everything working well now. Thanks for your time!